# Deployed NextJS over Firebase but getting Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: reactjs, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I just deployed my NextJS app over Firebase Hosting and Firebase Functions. After the deployment is successful, I went to the website but I was greeted with this page.

[image]

this is my `firebase.json`

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextApp"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm install",
      "npm run build"
    ],
    "runtime": "nodejs12",
    "ignore": [
      "**/tests/**",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "jest.config.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

my cloud functions for nextJS

```js
// This file is an entry point for Firebase Function to serve NextJS
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({
  dev,
  conf: {
    distDir: '.next',
    future: {
      strictPostcssConfiguration: false,
      excludeDefaultMomentLocales: true,
      webpack5: false,
    },
  },
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextApp = functions.region('asia-southeast2').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('File: ' + req.originalUrl);
  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
});
```

I did check Google Cloud Console and made sure that I've added `allUsers` to the Cloud Function Invoker role, but it isn't helping.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, silly me I've figured it out. The issue is because I'm deploying the Cloud Function to **asia-southeast2** region but Firebase Hosting only able to access Cloud Functions hosted in **us-central1**.